# Bootstrap tooltip on Font Awsome icon in Modal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I have an input field with a Fontawesome icon that I added through `content` in my CSS file. This icon will only show on validation. I want to add bootstrap's tooltip to the icon, but I can't figure out a way to do this since my icon is on the CSS file and not on the HTML file.  [This is what I'm trying to achieve.](https://www.pinterest.cl/pin/135319163779503354/)

It might be important to note that I'm trying to achieve this in a modal.

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

```css
.input-validation-error input {
  border: 2px solid #f46262;
}

.input-validation-error input[type="text"] {
  position: relative;
}

.input-validation-error::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  color: #f46262;
  position: relative;
  content: "\f06a";
  font-weight: 900;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 36px;
  right: -210px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">


<form class="registration-form">
  <div class="form-group input-validation-error">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="I'm a tooltip">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally figured it out.  My z-index was causing trouble, so I changed it from:

```
z-index: 3;
```

to

```
z-index: 5 !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty "placeholder" div before the input and position it the same as the icon. Use the placeholder as the tooltip trigger...

```
.tooltip-trigger {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 36px;
  left: 210px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/VxFPfXj9oa

Comment: What you propose does work in your code. When I add it to my code, nothing happens.  I created a codeply document with a little bit more code that I'm using, so that you can perhaps help me figure out why the tooltip won't show:
http://codeply.com/go/SpzF4hKKf4

Comment: It answers your original question. I can't say why it doesn't work in your environment.